# Ruby on Rails updating gems ("gem update --system"), get error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

I'm running the command "gem update --system". I get the following error message. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm running Rails 1.9.2 patch 136 and ruby 3.0.3.

```
Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems/source_index.rb:62:in `installed_spec_directories': undefined method `path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems/source_index.rb:52:in `from_installed_gems'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems.rb:914:in `source_index'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:98:in `init_gemspecs'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems.rb:873:in `new'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems.rb:873:in `searcher'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems.rb:495:in `find_files'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems.rb:1034:in `load_plugins'
    from /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/rubygems-update-1.4.1/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from setup.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

My Environment looks as follows:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7

  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-12-25 patchlevel 136) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/woshea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:

    - /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial
    - /Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:

    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :benchmark => false
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:

    - http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2011-Jan-02, the RubyGems 1.4.0/1.4.1 release does not work with MRI Ruby 1.9. This is documented: see [the release post](http://blog.zenspider.com/2010/12/rubygems-version-140-has-been.html).

Since you are running MRI Ruby 1.9, please join me in waiting for an updated MRI Ruby 1.9 that will support an updated RubyGems 1.4.

Comment: Actually, the release announcement is slightly wrong. RubyGems 1.4.0/1.4.1 works just fine on Ruby 1.9, it's just YARV that's broken; at least JRuby works as expected. In fact, as of yesterday, JRuby ships with RubyGems 1.4.1 by default, both in Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've updated my answer accordingly.